# When does a Matrix can be considered an element of the dual space?

Tags: matrices, tensors, dual-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $T_2=(\mathbf{M}(\mathbb{F});+;\cdot)$ be the ring of $n\times m$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{F}$ in the usual sense. We denote elements in $T_2$ as $M(n;m)$. If we consider $T_2$ as rank 2 tensors, and let the set $$X=\{φ|φ\in B:T_2\times T_2\rightarrow\mathbb{F}\}$$
be the set of all bilinear forms in $T_2$, then, clearly the set:

$$S=\{x\cdot y|x=M(1;k); y=M(k;1);\\
k=1,2,…,n\}$$
is a trivial subset of X, and acts like a contraction $V\otimes V^*\in\mathbb{F}$ in $T_2$. Is the inclusion $S\subseteq X$ a proper inclusion? Are there any non-trivial bilinear forms in $T_2$ wich are not in $S$?

Comment: A bilinear form is an element of $S$ if and only if the matrix associated with that bilinear form has rank (as in the dimension of the image of a linear transformation) 1.

Comment: And if the matrices are of Rank 1, is $S$ a proper subset, or does it equals $S=X$?

Comment: Except in the trivial case that $\dim(T_2) = 1$, it is a proper subset.